# Trouble to receive data from RS485 encoder in TM4C1294

Tags: microcontroller, uart, communication, rs485, encoder

I am trying to read data from an absolute RS485 encoder Single turn "eCoder-20S". The controller is EK-TM4C1294 launchpad. I am using SN75716AP for converting RS485 to UART conversion.
The datasheet of encoder says, we have to send 0x02 to recieve the single turn data, and few other commands for other data, I tried every transmission, can see the transmission signal properly, but recieving is coming like a garbage value.
However, When I calibrate the encoder with its RS485 debugger, I can see the angles properly.
I have attached the code and the image of scope, where Yellow waves are the Recieving , means scope probe at 'R' pin of SN75716AP, and Blue is at the pin 'D' of SN75716AP, means transmition. any one can help, whats the problem.

Here is the link for datasheet of encoder:
https://clouddisk.alibaba.com/file/downloadFile.htm?spm=a2700.12243863.dt_1.1.2ce83e5fpGDcCA&appkey=OneChat&id=1752222418&parentId=1482926735&secOperateAliId=MC1IDX11hkYzXWL2_Yuq7bqPX1PIt2F_L8vj_JeS14sSs6vXEqPaOQJzrsqwBzuPrLWOwqC

Please find chapter 8 "Encoder Specification" where how data should be transmitted from the encoder is explained.

[image: Encoder_Recieve]

[image: Code stuck at UART on charget]

Code:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "driverlib/debug.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/uart.h"

uint32_t g_ui32SysClock;
unsigned int temp=0, temp2=0;
uint32_t ui32SysClock;
uint32_t Recieved_value;

#define BAUD_RATE 2500000
#define DE_PIN GPIO_PIN_4
#define RE_PIN GPIO_PIN_5
#define System_Clock_frequency 120000000

int main(void) {
    ui32SysClock = SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN 
                        | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_240), 
                        System_Clock_frequency);

    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);

    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA0_U0RX);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA1_U0TX);
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, DE_PIN);
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, RE_PIN);

    GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);

    UARTConfigSetExpClk(UART0_BASE, ui32SysClock, 2500000,
        (UART_CONFIG_WLEN_8 | UART_CONFIG_STOP_ONE | UART_CONFIG_PAR_NONE));

    do {
        // Write the same character using the blocking write function.  This
        // function will not return until there was space in the FIFO and
        // the character is written.
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, DE_PIN | RE_PIN, DE_PIN | RE_PIN);
        UARTCharPut(UART0_BASE, 0x00000002);
        SysCtlDelay(1600);

        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, DE_PIN|RE_PIN, 0);
        // cThisChar=UARTCharGet(UART0_BASE);
        while (!UARTCharsAvail(UART0_BASE)) {
            Recieved_value= UARTCharGet(UART0_BASE);
            temp2=Recieved_value;
        }
    } while(1);

    return(0);
}
```

[image: Waveforms of scope]

Comment: "recieving is coming like a garbage value", if the received data is in binary instead of ASCII, and you trying to print it as ASCII, it will show up as garbage...

Comment: But the transmission data is visible,

Comment: It would be useful to see the "garbage" data

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add new information. -- What signal is this yellow trace? It is clearly not a RS485 transmission. -- If the blue trace is the RS485 line, there is nothing more than your 0x02 trigger. -- Do you mean SN75176 instead of SN7516?

Comment: Yes I mean SN7516AP, and the yellow signal should be the recieving output signal but not coming, and blue trace is at the DI pin of my SN7516 which is connected to the TX pin of UART of my controller, its exactly my command signal of  0x02.

Comment: As I wrote, [edit] your question to correct that. Nobody expects information in the comments. -- "_Yes, I mean SN7516AP_" is contradictory. What is it, 75176 or 7516? Do you see the inserted **7**? -- It seems that you think that the values of the yellow signal will be received by the UART. Is this correct? I do not understand what you mean by "_output signal but not coming_". _Where_ shall it come? On the RS485 line? -- Again, [edit] your question to clarify!

Comment: I have edited the question now

Comment: Your received signal is seriously broken - it should be a series of pulses similar to the transmitted waveform.

Comment: SN75716AP doesn't seem to be an valid part number. SN75176AP is - see https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75176a.pdf. Is there a typo in the part number in the question?

Comment: The yellow trace on the 'R' pin looks like it might not be actively driven but somehow coupled to the transmit data on the 'D' pin (blue trace). Is the RE (Receive Enable (active low) pin connected and what is the level on the RE pin?

Comment: The datasheet of SN75716AP:
https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/213954/TI/SN75176AP.html

The data sheet says, DE is active high, and RE is active low, both pins are connected to PA4, and PA5 of microcontroller, 
I am making the pin DE and RE high at transmision, and making them low at reciving

Comment: The SN75176AP operates from a 5V supply and the TM4C1294NCPDT uses 3.3V IO. Can you show a complete schematic for how the SN75176AP is connected?

Comment: I am giving the supply from a 5v power supply, but the ground of TM4C1294 and the power supply is common now

Comment: I meant that since the N75176AP operates from a 5V supply and the TM4C1294NCPDT uses 3.3V IO, is there a level translator between the two to allow for the difference in IO levels?

Comment: Also, can you edit the question to include a link to the datasheet for the _absolute RS485 encoder Single turn "eCoder-20S"_

Comment: No, I haven't used any level translator, let me try it.
I have edited the question to add the link to open datasheet,

Comment: I am using the level shifter now between UART pins PA0, and PA1 of the microcontroller, and R, and D pins of  SN75716A, and also between , DE<RE of SN75716A5, and GPIO pins of the microcontroller, still getting the same result.

Comment: I have added two pictures in my question, one is for the recieve waveform I am getting, now from encoder at the pin R of SN75716, but when I connect the pin 'R' of SN75716 to the Rx pin of My controller 'PA0', the code stuck and, transmit and recieve both stops, i have also added snapshot of the function of UART.C where my controller stuck.